# Unable to make django work: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Troubles

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install an project I cloned from googlecode: [1](https://github.com/hubert3/iSniff)
Unfortunately, I never worked with django and I'm stuck with a problem which I was unable to solve after reading the official documentation and after googl'ing. Nevertheless I think it is a simple problem, I must be missing something trivial.

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Is the errormessage that makes me go crazy. I tried to set it to different values, and also did I set the `PYTHONPATH` to consider the folder where my scripts are:

```
$ echo $PYTHONPATH
$ /home/user/iSniff-GPS/iSniff-GPS
$ pwd
$ /home/user/iSniff-GPS
```

The folder containing `models.py` is: `/home/user/iSniff-GPS/iSniff-GPS`

When I set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to a value the error message changes:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'iSniff-GPS' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named iSniff-GPS
```

Can you help me? What value should I set where?
Thanks in advance

Comment: is `iSniff-GPS` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Hello, yes it is in the file `settings.py` located in `/home/user/iSniff-GPS/iSniff_GPS`

Comment: Ok.. is there an `__init__.py` in the package ?

Comment: yes, there is. But it is empty

Comment: yeah.. its fine if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question:

The path in $PYTHONPATH is

```
/home/user/iSniff-GPS/iSniff-GPS
```

But your actual path is

```
/home/user/iSniff-GPS/iSniff_GPS
```

Please update us the the actual directory structure and how are you running the project?